# How can I add script to Dynamics Crm main.aspx page?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, xrm

I try to disable specific user login using javascript. If the user tries to login, I will close the window. I saw some examples about adding scripts to main.aspx page but it did not work.

Please help.

Comment: There are better, **supported** ways of not allowing a user to log in to CRM.  The best way is to disable the user.  If you only want a user to not log into a certain form, you can also use security roles to not allow them to see the form.

Comment: I do not want the user see the customizations I did.

Comment: but you want them to see vanilla CRM?

Comment: I want them use credentials for only coding side. They do not need to see customizations.

Comment: This makes no sense...first, if they are so determined to get access they could just bypass the JavaScript (about 2 minutes of work in Fiddler.) Why in the world you would do this - given that it is unsupported and will only stop undetermined people (who likely wouldn't even know the URL to start with or have any interest in improperly accessing the system.)

Comment: @Nicknow agreed - I gave up trying to help when his answers continued to be non-sensical

Comment: I did not mean people who likely wouldn't even know the URL to start with or have any interest in improperly accessing the system, there is a specific user, I also did not insist on that javascript is the only solution. I only asked for help, If you cannot help, save your no sense comments to yourselves.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I solved it. I added

```
<script>

this.onload=function(){
if(USER_GUID.indexOf("{D9D73FD0-F377-E511-85D2-000C29458CDD}") > -1)
{
 window.location.replace(null);
}
}   
</script>
```

before the closing body tag in main.aspx

Comment: Modifying the main.aspx is an unsupported customization.